# I am having duplicate definitions even though I am using header guards.

Tags: c++, header-files

I have 4 files I am currently working with.

- main.cpp
- subFunctions.cpp: has all function declarations for functions I use frequently
- variables.h: has global variables which are used by both main.cpp and subFunctions.cpp
- forwardFunctionDeclarations.h: has forward declarations for subFunctions.cpp

So main has included variables.h as well as forwardFunctionDeclarations.h. subFunctions.cpp also has included variables.h because as I've said it needs them. For header guards I am using for variables.h:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

//contents...

#endif
```

and the same thing for forwardFunctionDeclarations.h as well except changing the conditional phrase.

However when I try to build the program, it gives me the error "... already defined in main.obj" for all my global variables in variables.h. I am under the impression that although variables.h is included in both main.cpp and subFunctions.cpp (because it needs to be), it wouldn't be duplicating the variables when compiling because of the header guards.

Comment: Your post seems to be missing a [mcve] but my guess is you're _defining_ the variables in your header files instead of simply _declaring_ them. Missing `extern` perhaps

Comment: Ah that is probably the issue. Thanks!